# Negative Log Likelihood cost

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, likelihood

For multiclass classification, does the negative log likelihood loss function only take the loss for the classification group? i.e

$$
C(\theta) \equiv \sum{}{}y_ilog(\hat{y}_i)
$$

Doesn't $y_i$ just go to zero for all groups except the actual group a given training sample belongs to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does. It could have been written as $$C(\theta)=\log \hat y_{c(i)}$$ where $c(i)$ equals to the actual class of the i-th sample, but then differentiating the loss with respect to parameters wouldn't be straightforward as in here.

Comment: Why does the binary version take into account both the loss for the correct and incorrect classification group?

Comment: Typically in multiclass classification problems, there are $c$ outputs, and we choose maximum of them as answer. But, in binary classification problems, you have only one output instead of two outputs (that's the way the classifier is typically designed) as if $c=2$. That's why the loss term includes as if there is a second output